# Call to a member function getName() on a non-object product view page

Tags: magento-1.9, product-view, if

I have the following code on my ***product view page***, calling the product's containing ***category title*** :

```
   <div class="page-title category-title">
       <h1><?php echo $_category->getName(); ?></h1>
   </div>
```

The issue I have is that if a user visits the page directly (i.e. not through a category) then this results in a ***call to non-object error***. Can anyone suggest an edit so that ***when the user visits the product page directly*** the ***category title will not display***?

Answer (score 4):

**If you will access product from the category page you will get the category in the registry.** and if you access the product directly by URL you will need to fetch category name from product object.

```
<?php
if (Mage::registry('current_category')) {
    echo Mage::registry('current_category')->getName();
}
else {
    $categoryIds = $_product->getCategoryIds();
    if (count($categoryIds)) {
        $firstCategoryId = $categoryIds[0];
        $_category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($firstCategoryId);

        echo $_category->getName();
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

All you have to do is: check if the `$_category`-object that you reference is an object of the class `Mage_Catalog_Model_Category` or its descendants.

```
<?php if($_category instanceof Mage_Catalog_Model_Category): ?>
    <div class="page-title category-title">
       <h1><?php echo $_category->getName(); ?></h1>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: uhh.. sorry you were faster :)

Comment: and the answers keep coming :D anyway, you added some background to your answer

Comment: Yes. I am so happy to see the vibrant of our community at this time. CommunityRockzzzz :)

Answer (score 2):

You can check whether a category exist or not by `Mage::registry('current_category')`. ie Try this code.

```
<div class="page-title category-title">
    <h1>
    <?php if ($_category instanceof Mage_Catalog_Model_Category) : ?>
        <?php echo $_category->getName(); ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
    </h1>
</div>
```

Here I assume `$_category` holds `Mage::registry('current_category')`. ie

```
 <?php $_category = Mage::registry('current_category'); ?>
```

Comment: use rajeev another condition  here $_category->getId()... ` ($_category instanceof Mage_Catalog_Model_Category && ($_category->getId()>=1)) : `

Comment: @AmitBera Thanks for the suggestion. But see my last point. I said I am assuming `$_category` holds `Mage::registry('current_category')`. In that case, I am sure that `$_category` holds a **LOADED** category model (means category which has an id associated with it) or a **Null** Value. I feel hence it is an unwanted check then :)

Comment: :)..................

Answer (score 2):

All you have to do is check if the $_category-object that you
 reference is an object of the class `Mage_Catalog_Model_Category` or its
 descendants and it actually has value

An instance of return true when you have just created the object of category
 by `Mage::getModel('catalog/category');`

It should be like this :

```
<?php if($_category instanceof Mage_Catalog_Model_Category && $_category->getId()): ?>
    <div class="page-title category-title">
       <h1><?php echo $_category->getName(); ?></h1>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this code :

```
 $categoryIds = $_product->getCategoryIds();

        if(count($categoryIds) ){
            $firstCategoryId = $categoryIds[0];
            $_category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($firstCategoryId);

            echo $_category->getName();
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

for i understand the question you don't want to show `category name` if use access product page directly

```
<div class="page-title category-title">

       <h1><?php if (Mage::registry('current_category')) {

       $_category=Mage::registry('current_category');
      echo $_category->getName();
     } ?>
</h1>
```